# Can copy paste, open archive in Windows Explorer but can't read from code?

Tags: c#

I need to compute a SHA1 on a file that is changing often. I can copy, paste, open the archive in Windows Explorer, but I get an UnauthorizedAccessException on the `using` instruction.. The exception suggests I have a read only file, which doesn't seem to be true in the properties of the file.

The archive sits on a shared drive at a location that I have full access on.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace TheTest
{
    public class MakeSha1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"###.xml.gz", FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
                {
                    byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(fs);
                    StringBuilder formatted = new StringBuilder(hash.Length);
                    foreach (byte b in hash)
                    {
                        formatted.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", b);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(formatted.ToString());
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you mentioned exception so include at least message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor you are using for `FileStream` does not explicitly specify file sharing, and so no file sharing is permitted by default. If the file is being modified frequently, then you might be better off using a different form of the constructor:

```
using (fs = new FileStream(@"###.xml.gz", FileMode.Open, 
                           FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
{
    // ... your code here
}
```

Note that if another process modifies the file while you are processing, then your SHA1 will not be accurate.